# Running MSTests on real windows ce devices

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, mstest

Note : I'm using VS2008 SP1 and I'm working on windows 7.

I'm developing a Windows CE application which will run on Windows CE device.
I have created MSUnit test and tried to run it on real device

First run - **Test Run deployment issue:
The assembly or module 'Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container**

I added to ***Additional files and directories to deploy:***  this DLL.

Second run:

*Unable to set TestContext property for the class TestProject1.ConfigurationServiceTest. Error:  System.ArgumentException: Object with type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext" cannot be converted to the type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext"..*

Error Stack Trace:

> System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo
>   culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters,
>   Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature
>   sig) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
>   value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
>   value, Object[] index)
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.SetTestContext()

- device is connected with PC per USB, ActiveSync
- TestProject1 directory has been. As I mentioned TestProject1 has been **not** deployment.

SmartDeviceTestRun.testrunConfig settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c09FK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EccwV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEAaG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3mIh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tWyX.png

How can/should/must deploy/run unit test project on device correctly?

P.S. Automatically generated code in test method is not changed.

Comment: How did you create the test project?  Did you right click in a method and select "Create Unit Tests"?  That's the only way to really create a Smart Device Unit Test Project. You *cannot* use the "Add New Project" wizard or a normal Test project.

Comment: Test project has been created using Add New Test -> Create a new Smart Device Visual C# Test Project with Target platform Windows CE and .NET Compact Framework Version 3.5 (the same version has been used in all libraries and EXEs)